# subprocess.Popen does not open exe

Tags: python, command-line

This works:

```
FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
sgargs = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Stone Giant\\exe\\stone_giant.exe -bundle-dir \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Stone Giant\\bundle\""
subprocess.call(sgargs, stdout=FNULL, stderr=FNULL, shell=False)
```

This does not work and doesn't give any error or info:

```
subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Stone Giant\\exe\\stone_giant.exe", "-bundle-dir \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Stone Giant\\bundle\""])
```

I want to use Popen so that it's non-blocking. What am I missing?

Comment: You made bundle-dir a single parameter, likely you want `["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Stone Giant\\exe\\stone_giant.exe", "-bundle-dir", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Stone Giant\\bundle\"]` (separate the parameters)

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much.

Comment: As an aside, although shell=False in your first example works on Windows (everything goes through a shell anyway) it would not work on linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example, you made `-bundle-dir \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Stone Giant\\bundle\` a single parameter. Under the hood, python escaped the space between the parameter name and the value and the program thought you passed a parameter literally named "-bundle-dir \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Stone Giant\bundle\".

Separate into multiple paramters

```
["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Stone Giant\\exe\\stone_giant.exe", 
    "-bundle-dir", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Stone Giant\\bundle\"]
```

Comment: For some reason Popen is blocking for me. My code does not continue unless I kill stone_giant.exe. I'm on python 2.7. Am I missing more parameters in Popen?

Comment: As long as you don't make any more calls to the methods on the Popen object it shouldn't block. I'm not sure what happens on windows if you try to exit the parent completely and don't have a windows machine handy to tes.t

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake and forgot to uncomment my `call` code from earlier. It's working fine now. Thanks!